# How to convert $http request into $resource request in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have this http request, working fine.

**Controller**

```
$scope.removeRow = function (od){
  var temp = "order_id=" + od.order_id + "&product_id=" + od.product_id + "&variant_id=" + od.varient_id;
  var req = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://<domain name>/api2/v1/delete_item_in_order',
      data: temp,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  });

  req.then(
      function (response) {
          alert('success')
      },
      function (error) {
          //$scope.details = response.data;
          alert(error.message);
      }
  ); 
}
```

**Service** code to get resource object:

```
sampleApp.factory('Order', function ($resource) {
   return $resource('http://<domain name>/api2/v1/orders/:id', {id: '@_id'},    {
      'get': {method:'GET'}

    });

});
```

**Question**

How to add custom method `removeRow` in `Order` service, such that I can use `$resource` instead of `$http` in  `$scope.removeRow()` in controller?

Comment: see my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310771/get-data-on-conditions-by-resource-angualrjs/36311255#36311255)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than returning a single function, you can return an object with as many methods in following way

```
sampleApp.factory('Order', function ($resource) { 

    var removeRow = function() {console.log()};
    var getResource = function)() {
        $resource('http://<domain name>/api2/v1/orders/:id', {id: '@_id'}, { 'get': {method:'GET'} }); 
    } 

    return { removeRow : removeRow, 
        getResource : getResource
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify the get method inside $resource, this is already predefined.

Factory:

```
sampleApp.factory('Order', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://<domain name>/api2/v1/orders/:id', {id: '@_id'}, null}).$promise;
});
```

Calling Method:

```
$scope.removeRow = function (od){
    var temp = "order_id=" + od.order_id + "&product_id=" + od.product_id + "&variant_id=" + od.varient_id;

    Order.save(temp).then(function(result){
        alert('success');
    }, function(err){
        alert(err.message);
    });
};
```