# How to configure AngularJS to accept query string with multiple parameters

Tags: angularjs, resources

How to configure AngularJS to accept query string with multiple parameters

"http://example.com:8090/rest/prototype/1/search/site?type=page&label=global:policy"

This is my solution and is not working

```
return $resource('http://example.com:8090/rest/prototype/1/search/site?type=page&label=global:policy', {},
                {
                    query: {
                        method: 'GET',
                        isArray: true,
                        params:{type:'page',
                                label:'global:policy' },
                        "Content-Type": "application/xml",
                        "Accept": "application/xml",
                        "Authorization":'Basic ' + appSettings.base64,
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,authorization",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":true 
                    }
                })
            },
```

The call like that:

```
policyService.query({type:'page',
                                label:'global:policy' },function(data)
            {
                OnSuccess(data);
            }, OnError) ;
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Look at my answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310771/get-data-on-conditions-by-resource-angualrjs/36311255#36311255

Comment: Thanks Aravinthan for sharing your solution.